# How to show/hide input value on focus?

Tags: javascript, forms, input, hide, show

I see this all over the web, but was wondering if anyone has the JavaScript code for the EASIEST way to show input value on blur, but hide in on focus.

Comment: Huh? What do you mean by show? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: So the input will have for example "Search..." inside of it, and when you go click on the input, it would go blank. I believe I already have the answer, but thanks anyway Ian! =]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073428/what-the-best-way-to-display-a-default-text-in-textbixes-and-textareas/1073514#1073514

Answer (score 17):

This always worked for me:

```
<input 
    type="text" 
    value="Name:"
    name="visitors_name" 
    onblur="if(value=='') value = 'Name:'" 
    onfocus="if(value=='Name:') value = ''"
 />
```

Answer (score 17):

Since this still comes up on google, I'd like to point out that with HTML 5 you can use the placeholder attribute with an input to achieve this in one piece of html.

```
<input type="text" id="myinput" placeholder="search..." />
```

Placeholder is now standard across modern browsers, so this really would be the preferred method.

Answer (score 7):

I prefer jQuery way:

```
$(function(){
    /* Hide form input values on focus*/ 
    $('input:text').each(function(){
        var txtval = $(this).val();
        $(this).focus(function(){
            if($(this).val() == txtval){
                $(this).val('')
            }
        });
        $(this).blur(function(){
            if($(this).val() == ""){
                $(this).val(txtval);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

It is modified [Hide Form Input Values On Focus With jQuery](http://zackperdue.com/plugins/hide-form-input-values-on-focus-with-jquery) by Zack Perdue.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest approach I know of is the following:

```
<input 
    name="tb" 
    type="text" 
    value="some text"
    onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value = 'some text'" 
    onfocus="if (this.value=='some text') this.value = ''"  />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don’t care about valid HTML, you use the `placeholder` attribute. It will work out of the box on a Safari, and you can add some unobtrusive JS to mimic this behavior in other browsers.

More reading:

- http://www.beyondstandards.com/archives/input-placeholders/ (JS implementation)
- http://lab.dotjay.co.uk/experiments/forms/input-placeholder-text/

And google. ;-)

The solution is similar to the one Josh Stodola posted, but it’s more flexible and universal.

Comment: I guess not to care about valid HTML is never good, isn't it? Moreover just optimizing for one browser...

Comment: Validator is only a tool. You can ignore it’s output as long as you know what you’re doing. And optimizing for the upcoming standard isn’t so bad after all :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use on [my blog](http://blog.js-development.com). Just go there and check out the source code behind.

```
function displaySearchText(text){
    var searchField = document.getElementById('searchField');
    if(searchField != null)
        searchField.value = text;
}
```

Your input field should look something like this:

```
<input id='searchField' name='q' onblur='displaySearchText("Search...");' onfocus='displaySearchText("");' onkeydown='performSearch(e);' type='text' value='Search...'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**For all browsers:**

```
<input onfocus="if(this.value == 'Your value') { this.value = '';}" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Your value';}" value="Your value" type="text" name="inputname" />
```

**For newest version of browsers:**

```
<input type="text" name="inputname" placeholder="Your value" />
```