# How to get rid of text after clicking in the form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a guestbook form with this code:

```
<input class='tbox' type='text' value='Type here' name='code_verify' size='15' maxlength='20'>
```

How can I get rid of the text after clicking at the "type here" box?

What i mean is when I click in the field "type here" the words "type here" must dissapear and give a blinking cursor.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: So we need more information. you say you use a CMS, which one? Does it not like double quotes or what happens? How does view-source look like with my example in it?

Comment: User **marines** gave a link-only answer which might get removed. Contents copied here to preserve the link: *Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077859/how-to-show-hide-input-value-on-focus -marines*

Answer (score 0):

With js like this

```
<input class='tbox' type='text' value='Type here' name='code_verify' 
size='15' maxlength='20' onfocus="if (this.value == 'Type here') { this.value=''}">
```

Comment: When i put this in the form the screen gets blank and the page does not load. It's part of a plugin for my cms. To be honest i don't know much about js :/ But want to learn! Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input class="tbox" type="text" 
onfocus="if (this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value=''"  
onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value=this.defaultValue"  
value="Type here" name="code_verify" size="15" maxlength="20:>
```